# Does Ubuntu 12.04 support Hot plugging

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, hotplug

I have a motherboard that supports Hot plugging and a Power Supply that also supports this. Does Ubuntu support doing a Hard Drive Hot plugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be the case. I really could only find one discussion of the practice from 2010 but that gives me hope that it as even matured since then:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8874139

Comment: Readin that post made me make a small "test" that had my heart out. I first removed the Sata cable then the Sata power cable from a 1TB HDD. Then connected another HDD in its places. Connected the Sata Power cable and then the Sata Interface cable. Ubuntu recognized the HDD correctly right away. Also Nautilus added in the panel the Hard drive and the Ubuntu launcher added the HDD to the launcher icons. Works out of the box. But you know, the first time is scary.